# How to align CenterVertical in Relative layout programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a linear layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
  android:id="@+id/linearLayoutImages"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:weightSum="1">
</LinearLayout>
```

The following function gets a bitmap, sets it to an image view that has been created programmatically, then creates a trash can icon and puts the whole things into a relative layout and finally puts it into the linear layout. But there is a problem, I want the result to be like this:

[image: the true result]

but the result becomes like this:

[image: the false result]

Code:

```
fun setImage(bitmap: Bitmap){

    try {
        val params = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(375, 375)
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP)
        params.setMargins(9,0,9,0)

        val imageViewShowPic = ImageView(this)
        imageViewShowPic.setLayoutParams(params)
        imageViewShowPic.id = View.generateViewId()
        imageViewShowPic.requestLayout()

        val params2 = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)


        val relativeLayout = RelativeLayout(this)
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(params2)
        relativeLayout.requestLayout()

        val params3 = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(75,75)
        params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,imageViewShowPic.id)
        params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL)

        val imageButtonDelete = ImageButton(this)
        imageButtonDelete.setLayoutParams(params3)
        imageButtonDelete.requestLayout()

        relativeLayout.addView(imageViewShowPic)
        relativeLayout.addView(imageButtonDelete)

        linearLayoutImages.addView(relativeLayout)

        imageViewShowPic.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        imageButtonDelete.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_delete)

        imageButtonDelete.setOnClickListener {
            linearLayoutImages.removeView(relativeLayout)
        }
    }
    catch (ex:Exception)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,ex.message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

### Update

The linear layout itself is in a horizontal scroll view, if it makes any difference.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollViewImages"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonAddPic">

                <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutImages"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1"></LinearLayout>
 </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author)*.

I finally found the solution myself! I changed the relative layout to a vertical linear layout (I don't know if it matters or not):

```
val params2 = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

    val linearLayout = LinearLayout(this)
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params2)
    linearLayout.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
    linearLayout.requestLayout()
```

and then set the width of imageButtonDelete to match parent.

```
val params3 = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)


    val imageButtonDelete = ImageButton(this)
    imageButtonDelete.setLayoutParams(params3)
    imageButtonDelete.requestLayout()
    imageButtonDelete.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the below code you can achieve the desired output.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayoutImages"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1"></LinearLayout>
```

**In Your activity**.

```
    try {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(375, 375);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        params.setMargins(9, 0, 9, 0);

        ImageView imageViewShowPic = new ImageView(this);
        imageViewShowPic.setLayoutParams(params);
        imageViewShowPic.setId(View.generateViewId());
        imageViewShowPic.requestLayout();

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(params2);
        relativeLayout.requestLayout();

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(75, 75);
        params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, imageViewShowPic.getId());
        params3.topMargin = 30;
        params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        ImageButton imageButtonDelete = new ImageButton(this);
        imageButtonDelete.setLayoutParams(params3);
        imageButtonDelete.requestLayout();

        relativeLayout.addView(imageViewShowPic);
        relativeLayout.addView(imageButtonDelete);

        linearLayoutImages.addView(relativeLayout);

        imageViewShowPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
        imageButtonDelete.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Comment: It doesn't have such an option. It just has CENTER_VERTICAL, CENTER_HORIZONTAL, CENTER_IN_PARENT.

Comment: Use `CENTER_HORIZONTAL`

Comment: Sorry but it gets worse! This way the image view goes to the right side of scroll view and the trash can goes to the opposite side in the left.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I don't understand why it doesn't work for me. When I set the params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL); it spreads the pictures and makes a long horizontal scroll view. Can it be because of the horizontal scroll view?

Comment: Have you done change in the linearLayout?  As i added `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` in that

Comment: Maybe that is because of the HorizontalScrollView. Try by fixing the width of the `RelativeLayout` by the width of image + some padding.

Comment: If you are using HorizontalScrollView for this type of listing than i suggest you to move to RecyclerView

Comment: If you could take a look at this app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.recettetek&hl=en_GB) it'll be great. Go to New Recipe activity and add some images, it sets the images in a horizontal line with a trash can image. I want something like that.

Comment: Ya you can use RecyclerView with horizontal orientation for this. Manually adding view will be a headache in this.

Comment: OK Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Set (RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL) to (RelativeLayout.CENTER)

```
val params3 = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(75,75)
params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,imageViewShowPic.id)
params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER)
```

and

android:layout_width="wrap_content" to  android:layout_width="match_parent"

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutImages"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1"></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It doesn't have such an option. It just has CENTER_VERTICAL, CENTER_HORIZONTAL and CENTER_IN_PARENT. And the second thing didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: set it center_horizontal

Comment: Sorry but it gets worse! This way the image view goes to the right side of scroll view and the trash can goes to the opposite side in the left.